# linear equations has an infinite number of solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Hi Please help me with this question

The following system of linear equations has an infinite number of solution

$ 2x−4y−z=−11$

$ −x−5y+2z=−14$

$ 2x−4y−z=−11$

Solve the system and find the solution in the form $(x,y,z)$,$ t$, where $t$ is a free parameter.
When you write the solution, however, only write the part $(x,y,z)$ as a unit vector. Approximate your solution to the second decimal figure (e.g. $\pm 0.01$).

Comment: Help us help you by showing your work and where you’re getting stuck. This is not a homework-solving site.

Answer (score 1):

Perform row operations on the augmented matrix until its l.h.s. is in reduced row echelon form:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2&-4&-1&-11\\-1&-5&2&-14
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}&\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&5&-2&14 \\2&-4&-1&-11
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&5&-2&14 \\0&-14&3&-39
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&5&-2&14 \\0&1&-\frac 3{14}&-\frac{39}{14}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
&\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&5&-2&14 \\0&1&-\frac 3{14}&-\frac{39}{14}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{rr|r|r}
1&0&-\frac{13}{14}&\frac{391}{14} \\0&1&-\frac 3{14}&-\frac{39}{14}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
so the solutions are
$$x=\frac{13z+391}{14},\enspace y=\frac{3z-39}{14},\quad\text{or, in vector form:}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{391}{14}\\-\frac{39}{14}\\0\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}\frac{13}{14}\\-\frac{3}{14}\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
There remains to normalise the directing vector $\;\begin{bmatrix}\frac{13}{14}\\-\frac{3}{14}\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the second equation by $2$ and adding to the first we get
$$6y+3z=39$$
the last and first equations are the same so we have only Solutions in the form
$$2y+z=-13$$ (after dividing by $2$)